# Вызов функции по строковому названию

Tags: c++, рефлексия

Как вызвать функцию по строковому имени?

Пример использования:

```
void foo() {}

void bar() {}

int main() {
    call("foo"); // вызывает первую функцию
    call("bar"); // вызывает вторую функцию  
}
```

Как написать такой `call`?

Достаточно решения для самых простых случаев - нешаблонных ничего не возвращающих функций без перегрузок.

Comment: Если расположить функции в динамических библиотеках, то можно вызывать, предварительно загрузив библиотеку и получая указатель на функцию по имени.

Comment: @Croessmah Если расположить так, чтобы хранились имена, а не только ординалы...

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo() { cout << "foo\n"; }
void bar() { cout << "bar\n"; }

typedef void (*funcptr)();

pair<const char*,funcptr> fs[] = { {"bar",bar}, {"foo",foo}};

void call(const char * fname)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(fs)/sizeof(*fs); ++i)
        if (strcmp(fs[i].first,fname)== 0)
        {
            fs[i].second();
            break;
        }
}


int main() {
    call("foo"); // вызывает первую функцию
    call("bar"); // вызывает вторую функцию  
}
```

Например, так. Вопрос только - **зачем?!**

Comment: Если я заранее знаю все названия функций то незачем, тогда можно просто вызвать. Интересно, как не имея заранее созданного соответствия (массива в вашем примере) вызывать.

Comment: Никак. Такого средства (рефлексии) в C++ нет... Да и очень это было бы небезопасно, кстати...

Comment: Вы уверены, что Вам надо именно это? Расскажите, чего Вы хотите добиться, может это можно сделать проще?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов вызвать функции в файле по названиям. Названия получаются обработкой этого файла как текста.

Comment: @дюдя *"вызвать функции в файле по названиям"* Это понятно, но зачем? *"получаются обработкой этого файла как текста"* То есть у вас уже есть способ автоматически получать названия? Тогда что мешает автоматически генерировать код с массивом как в этом ответе?

Comment: В принципе можно вытащить из таблицы символов (если бинарник не стрипнут) и рассчитать адрес. Для С++ можно и прототип из имени восстановить. (вообще, посмотрите на отладчик, он умеет делать такие штучки)

Comment: @avp Это если информация об именах хранится. А если нет? Отладчик умеет, если есть нужная информация. В общем случае, если строка с именем (пусть и декорированным) не хранится - фиг что найдешь... А если хранится - так я это и делал :)

Answer (score 1):

можно так, для функций с одинаковыми сигнатурами

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

namespace Caller
{
  std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> functions;
  void call(const std::string& functionName);
}

void Caller::call(const std::string& functionName)
{
  functions[functionName]();
}


void foo() 
{ 
  std::cout << "foo\n"; 
}
void bar() 
{ 
  std::cout << "bar\n"; 
}


int main()
{
  Caller::functions["foo"] = foo;
  Caller::functions["bar"] = bar;

  Caller::call("foo");
  Caller::call("bar");

  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

если вызываем call с функцией которой нет в словаре, то создаться новый элемент автоматически и вызовется function по умолчанию, который бросит исключение, поэтому нужно или перехватить исключение или же обработать этот момент например как @Harry c поиском функции заранее

вариант с ловлей исключения:

```
void Caller::call(const std::string& functionName)
{
  try {
    functions[functionName]();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Нужно обязательно сначала выполнять поиск - иначе `functions[functionName]();` при отсутствии `functionName` в контейнере создаст такой элемент с "пустой" функцией, и получится хреново... :( Так что нужно что-то вроде `if (auto it = functions.find(functionName); it != functions.end()) it->second();
else /* Обработка ошибки */`